# How to transfer post id from a foreach loop to a report page having a form for report the post in laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

## First Page:

```
@foreach(items as item)
<div> ID : {{ item->id }} </div>
<div> Title : {{ item->title }} </div>
<div> <a href="{{ route('report') }}">Report Post Form</a> </div>
@endforeach
```

## Second Page:

How to get id and user details in report post form page ?

Comment: use your post id as an argument or parameter going to the second page, the second page then uses that id and fetch that details based on it. so it could be simply as `report/23` or something. you'd need to edit the route, then use the argument that is passed along that route.

Answer (score 0):

Update route params

```
@foreach($items as $item)
<div> ID : {{ $item->id }} </div>
<div> Title : {{ $item->title }} </div>
<div> <a href="{{ route('report',$item->id) }}">Report Post Form</a> </div>
@endforeach
```

Then in route

```
Route::get('report/{id}',[YourController::class,'report'])->name('report')
```

and in controller

```
public function report($id){

   $post=Post::find($id);

  return view('viewName',compact('post'))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

at first you should fix your route file and change it like this :

```
Route::get('report/{id}',YourController::class@method);
```

and just pass the id

```
@foreach(items as item)
<div> ID : {{ item->id }} </div>
<div> Title : {{ item->title }} </div>
<div> <a href="{{ route('report',$item->id) }}">Report Post Form</a> </div>
@endforeach
```

and now u can get the id with request() in your controller